# Errors on References

Tags: silverlight, reference, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8

here is the picture of the errors that i get after i referenced a few dll's, end a class i need to use for the specific viewmodel

[image]

And here is a picture of my references tab in solution explorer, all these references i added through the Nuget Package Manager.

[image]

i did google it, and every answer comes out that someone didnt add the neccesary reference,
i added everything needed for this project to run, can someone please point me in the right direction?

i am using Visual Studio 2012/Windows Phone 8 SDK/C#/Silverlight

Thanks

Comment: I had similar problems with Visual Studio 2012. After I downloaded and installed the Visual Studio Update 1, most of them go away. In my case, they were just design-time errors, not run-time, and if I tried to confirm any of the errors by double clicking on the error, I would see that everything was OK, so the errors were just a design-time irritation. I could still work.

Comment: I see no reason why you should be getting the problem you have unless it's tied to things being in different projects and the references not being correctly managed between them. Are you able to share the solution or create a simple repro?

Answer (score 0):

you must import them in the mane space
Doing sone Using System.**.NewtonSoft or usin **..**Newtonsoft ...